# Why is there an error when adding a subscription plan?

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to add a subscription plan to a user using cloud code, but I get this error in the Xcode console

[image]

and this error in stripe

[image]

Below is the cloud code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Subscription", function(request, response){
Stripe.Subscriptions.create({
customer: request.params.customerId,
plan: request.params.plan
},{
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    response.success(customer);
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    response.error(httpResponse);
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Parse's Stripe library is many years old and does not support the subscriptions api. Also parse is shutting down soon.

Comment: Yes I am aware, but I should still be able to run any JavaScript Script right?

Comment: You could manually install the Stripe-Node SDK, but you'll discover that parse-node does not support having folders or subdirectories in your cloud code directory nor does it support the Node calls Stripe makes to find out things like your user-agent.